# webapi HttpGet field is required even though it has default value

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I thought that I can make optional fields like this...

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Foobar> GetFoobar(
    string DateRange = null,
    string Version = null)
{
    return service.GetAll(DateRange, Version);
}
```

But the api is failing with 400...

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-4d3cb9173485547bfb36cb2a723725c2-f39d9a1bd4fad052-00",
  "errors": {
    "DateRange": [
      "The DateRange field is required."
    ],
    "Version": [
      "The Version field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the reason.  To be optional, the parameter MUST be nullable (even if it is a reference type and does not make any sense!!!).

For example,

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Foobar> GetFoobar(
    string? DateRange = null,
    string? Version = null)
{
    return service.GetAll(DateRange, Version);
}
```

With question mark after the `string` this will work correctly.